# What does energy meter class 0.2S , 0.5S, 1S means?

Tags: power, ac, mains, energy

I was checking the datasheet of an energy meter IC (Atmel M90E36A) and found an application saying " **Poly-phase energy meters of class 0.2S, 0.5S and class 1 which are used in three-phase four-wire (3P4W, Y0) or three-phase three-wire (3P3W, Y or Δ) systems.**"
[image]

It would be helpful if anyone explains what's the term "Meters of class 0.2S, 0.5S and Class 1 .." signifies.

Answer (score 3):

It applies to the accuracy. Details are described in IEC Standard 62053-11.

This standard costs money unfortunately. But this document summarized some of the standards content.
https://www.satec-global.com/sites/default/files/Application-note_Accuracy-Class_July2018.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy class refers to the full scale error of an instrument. We can calculate the "percentage error in reading" of an instrument if its accuracy class is specified.

% Error in reading = (Full Scale Value/Measured value)*(Accuracy class)

The full scale value of an instrument is the maximum value that can be measured by the instrument.

For example, if you have a class 1 ammeter having a full scale value of 100mA, it means that it has an error in reading of +/- 1% for a measured value of 100mA.
This does not mean that the error in reading will be same for all values measured. The error increases as your measured value deviates from the full scale value. Normally, we would limit our measurements within 1/3 of the full scale value of the instrument to avoid such large errors.

Comment: Which may or may not translate to an error of 10% on a 10mA reading; the devil is in the details (presumably spelled out at length in the standard)

Comment: @user_1818839 It all depends on the full scale value of the instrument that we are using. Normally, you wouldn't use an instrument to measure values less than 1/3 of the full scale value to avoid large errors.

Comment: Right. You know this; my note was in case the questioner automatically jumped to "oh it's 1% accurate" without qualification.